# Firebase email verification WITHOUT creating and account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an Android application that will deliver notifications.
Users can opt-in with a phone number or an email account.

I just need to verify the email the user entered, I don't want to **create** a Firebase account

Firebase has a `FirebaseUser#sendEmailVerification()` but that will require to create an account.

In other words, I just want the email verification **to be the same as the Phone verification**, where Firebase will just send you a code or verification link.

Is there a way to leverage Firebase email verification without creating an account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone trying to accomplish the same, here's how I was able to do it.

Go to Fibrebase console and enable `Email/Password` and `Anonymous` sign-in methods on the Authentication screen

[Firebase Authentication screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AeFh.jpg)

Then in you code, create an **Anonymous user** (this is what does the trick, because now you have a *valid* user to verify against), change the email, and then send a verification. After that, reload the Firebase user and check `isEmailVerified()`

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() == false) {
                    mAuth.getCurrentUser().updateEmail("<MAIL YOU WANTO TO VERIFY HERE>");
                    mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification();
                    Log.e(TAG, "mail sent.....................................");
                }

                //updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here's the reloading part:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().reload()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.e(TAG,( mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() ? "VERIFIED" : "Not verified"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: ah. so you update the top-level email when the user adds one and just store them in the user object in the database

Answer (score 0):

Both phone number verification and email verification are tied to a Firebase Authentication account. There is no way to use them with such an account, since the result of a verification is that a the relevant property (`email_verified` or `phone_number`) in the user account gets updated.

Comment: Not true, the phone verification process on Firebird is NOT tied to an account. You can call `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber` freely. I don't see why we CAN verify phones but we CAN'T verify emails without an account.