# Firebase Auth, email verification without creating a user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to do email verification through Firebase. My app only accepts phone authentication from users. I also want to send email verification as an additional secondary verification. But I don't want to do createUser.

I only need a verification code.

Is there a way?

Comment: Look at the trick this developer used: 1. Create an anonymous user, 2. Set their email address, 3. Send verification email.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466223/209103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want to do createUser.

There is no way you can verify an email without creating the user first. isEmailVerified is a field that exists inside the FirebaseUser object. If the user doesn't exist, then the FirebaseUser object will be null, so you have to deal with nullity.

> Is there a way?

There isn't. You need to have the user created first.